# Match each index of multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

```
   $msg =  Array
(

    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 638
            [user_id] => 358253
            [raw_text] => Your package with Philips QG3387 Multi Grooming Kit (Black) has been successfully delivered. Thank you for choosing us.
            [type_of_message] => ECOMMERCE
            [sub_type_of_message] => DELIVERY_STATUS
            [product_description] => Philips QG3387 Multi Grooming Kit (Black)

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 641
            [user_id] => 358253
            [raw_text] => Your package with Philips QG3387 Multi Grooming Kit (Black) could not be delivered as addressee was not available. www.amazon.in/track
            [type_of_message] => ECOMMERCE
            [sub_type_of_message] => DELIVERY_STATUS
            [product_description] => Philips QG3387 Multi Grooming Kit (Black)

        )



    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 907
            [user_id] => 358253
            [raw_text] => Dispatched: Your package with Gadget Advice 720*480 Newest Smiley Face DVR Hidden S... will be delivered on or before 16-Jul. Track at http://amzn.in/5bIkuau
            [type_of_message] => ECOMMERCE
            [sub_type_of_message] => 
            [product_description] => Your package with Gadget Advice 720*480 Newest Smiley Face DVR Hidden S...

        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 910
            [user_id] => 358253
            [raw_text] => Your order with order id 171-5257992-6082713 has been successfully placed. Please check email for more details. Thank you for shopping at Amazon.
            [type_of_message] => ECOMMERCE
            [sub_type_of_message] => 
            [product_description] => 

        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 914
            [user_id] => 358253
            [raw_text] => Your order with order id 404-4813325-2653153 has been successfully placed. Please check email for more details. Thank you for shopping at Amazon.
            [type_of_message] => ECOMMERCE
            [sub_type_of_message] => 
            [product_description] => 

        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 922
            [user_id] => 358253
            [raw_text] => Your package with Philips QG3387 Multi Grooming Kit (Black) has been successfully delivered. Thank you for choosing us.
            [type_of_message] => ECOMMERCE
            [sub_type_of_message] => DELIVERY_STATUS
            [product_description] => Philips QG3387 Multi Grooming Kit (Black)

        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 925
            [user_id] => 358253
            [raw_text] => Your package with Philips QG3387 Multi Grooming Kit (Black) could not be delivered as addressee was not available. www.amazon.in/track
            [type_of_message] => ECOMMERCE
            [sub_type_of_message] => DELIVERY_STATUS
            [product_description] => Philips QG3387 Multi Grooming Kit (Black)

        )
)
```

I want to compare $msg[0][product_description] with $msg[1][product_description] for each index and create a new array

```
if($msg[0][product_description] != $msg[1][product_description]) then $newArr[] = $msg[0][product_description]
if($msg[0][product_description] == $msg[1][product_description]) then $newArr[] = $msg[1][product_description]
if($msg[1][product_description] == $msg[2][product_description]) then $newArr[] = $msg[2][product_description]
```

I want to compare $msg[0][product_description] with other indexes if the value is same then move that index to new array. Same comparison with other indexes.
Please help

Comment: It is not clear to me what your goal actually is, but it seems as you need a loop like a **for** loop

Comment: @bub In above array i want to match each production_description field if we found the same value then move last index having same value to move into new array

Comment: Your example is not clear : you speak about index and value.
Do you need to have the last 'product_description' value find in $msg and remove the concerned index from $msg ?

Comment: for any product_description == Philips QG3387 Multi Grooming Kit (Black), i want last array having this value and unset the rest

Comment: Please add desired output of 'new array'